# Iterating over lists produces unexpected results

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the first example below, I am iterating over a list of dataframes. The For loop creates column 'c'. Printing each df shows that both elements in the list were updated.

In the second example, I am iterating over a list of variables. The For loop applys some math to each element. But when printing, the list does not reflect the changes made in the For loop.

Please help me to understand why the elements in the second example are not being impacted by the For loop, like they are in the first example.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['a', 'b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3,4],[5,6]], columns=['a', 'b'])

dfs = [df1, df2]
for df in dfs:
    df['c'] = df['a'] + df['b']

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

result:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  3  4  7
   a  b   c
0  3  4   7
1  5  6  11
```

Second example:

```
a, b = 2, 3
test = [a, b]
for x in test:
    x = x * 2 
print(test)
```

result: `[2, 3]`

expected result: `[4, 6]`

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate in a list like this x takes the value at the current position.

```py
for x in test:
    x = x * 2
```

When you try to assign a new value to x you are not changing the element in the list, you are changing what the variable x contains.

To change the actual value in the list iterate by index:

```py
for i in range(len(test)):
    test[i] = test[i] * 2
```

Comment: Thank you. But why does it change the element in the list in the first example? I am not using an index there?

Comment: In the first example you are changing df['c']. If you were to assign a different value to df itself the same thing would happen.

Comment: You can change the inside of the list/object, The problem is you are assigning a different value to the variable itself. So x is no longer the element of the list. It is a new variable with the value you assigned.

Comment: When I create column 'c', this is making the value for df different, yet this is not considered assigning a new value to df? In the second example, x is referring to the element in the list, just like in the second example. I just don't quite understand why Sorry, I feel like I am close to grasping this, but not quite there yet.

Comment: Imagine a list with numbers from 1 to 10. Let's run your loop for that case. In the first iteration of the loop, x is going to be 1. You can use x like any other variable. When you write x = something you are not changing the first element of the list, you are changing the value of x. It started by being equal to 1 but if you say x = 10, x will be 10 but you only changed the variable x.  In the start  x -> test[0] -> 1 when you change the value of x to 10 it becomes x -> 10. Nothing happens to test[0]

Comment: Now in the case of df you have df -> {"c": 6} when you do df["c"] = 4 you are changing the inside of df so it becomes df -> {"c": 4}. If you were to do df = 1 it would become df = 1. This is hard to explain via text sorry.

Answer (score 2):

In your second example, `test` is a list of ints which are not mutable. If you want a similar effect to your first snippet, you will have to store something mutable in your list:

```py
a, b = 2, 3
test = [[a], [b]]
for x in test:
    x[0] = x[0] * 2 
print(test)
```

Output: `[[4], [6]]`